# React Native getting start project IOS build failed

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build

I am getting following errors while creating first React Native project (**AwesomeProject**). I have run this project on Android and it is working as expected. Please find the attached snapshots and guide me what is going wrong with IOS.

I was using Xcode 8 when getting errors I also updated my Xcode to 9.0 and Node etc.. but nothing got worked and all errors are same as I am getting since from start.

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/clines291/RNProjects/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Conv.o/Users/clines291/RNProjects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/third-party/folly-2016.09.26.00/folly/Conv.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
        CompileC /Users/clines291/RNProjects/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StringBase.o /Users/clines291/RNProjects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/third-party/folly-2016.09.26.00/folly/StringBase.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-    iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

**Attachments:**
[Visual Code build failed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndw00.png)
[Xcode build failed errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Fpa.png)

**Versions:** 
Xcode: 9.0 
Node: v8.6.0
Homebrew: 1.3.5
Watchman: 4.9.0
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.49.3
npm: 5.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found this solution on below mentioned link:**
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14368
react-native init [PROJECT_NAME] --version 0.44.0

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using xcode 8 rather than xcode 9?

or if you still want to use xcode 9
try this

```
rm -r ~/.rncache/
cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/
./configure --host arm-apple-darwin
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't worked! Same issue as above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is C compiler problem
[image]

open xcode, select Build Settings > Build options, 
then enable c compiler works me.